# Which database engine is best for node.js apps?

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, sqlite

I am looking for a database engine which is the best for storing thousands of records. I first wanted to use MySQL, because I know it best, but I'd like to have strong answer.

I need predefined columns, database can be as small as 10 MB or as "big" as 10 GB of data and it would be cool if that engine is fast for reads (insertions may be a bit slower). I don't need fast-fulltext-search or regexp searching. To give you an example - selecting items via slug extracted from link.

I saw [this site](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis) before but I still don't know what is best option for me.

So here is my question: Which database engine is best for uses like mine?

Comment: recommendations are opinion based and off topic as well

Comment: I found this question useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> database can be as small as 10 MB or as "big" as 10 GB of data

At that size, you could use virtually any database you want. Remember, 10 GBs of data is small enough to fit into memory on a modern server.

> I need predefined columns...

Sounds like SQL. Take you pick: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite... at that size it will barely matter, just use what you like.

The performance difference on a "few gigs" of data will be negligible.

Answer (score 17):

You should look at [MEAN stack](http://www.mean.io/). Personally, I like MongoDB - I use an ORM tool like [mongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/) - It increases your development speed rapidly. The one thing i really like about having Node JS, Express body parser, mongodb and mongoose is I deal everything on the server side in one language - Javascript and I expose REST services which can be consumed on Web (typically [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) - the A in MEAN stack or [backbone](http://backbone.js)) based application.

Comment: Pradeep, I have similar requirements. I am new for server side programming, bt with some research i felt node.js is better for my purpose. I have no Idea of setting up the server with node =.js for REStful web services which I want to use for a mobile application which I am developing. I look forward for some guidance over this.

Comment: @srv_sud: Mean has come a long way. Start at http://mean.io/#!/

Answer (score 4):

Look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).
And don't forget to look at [TokuMX](http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb/) - it's very promising!